# Как спрятать все строки таблицы, которые содержат нули?

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день!
Как можно по чекбоксу спрятать все строки таблицы, колонки которой содержат одни нули ?

Мне пока приходит в голову вариант, при котором все пустые строки имеют класс `< tr class="zero">` и с помощью `js` меняю `style`, но при этом вся таблица плывёт - ячейки становятся разной ширины.
Изначально таблицу создаю сам, поэтому есть возможность устанавливать классы и стили.

```js
//js файл
function toggle() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('zero');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked)
            rows[i].style.display = 'block';
        else
            rows[i].style.display = 'none'
    }
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
    <label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

    <table>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Ivanov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Petrov</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Sidorov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Morozov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tosterov</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Нашел данный способ на просторах инета. Сам только начал изучать JS.

P.S. Интересуют все варианты, но выделите, пожалуйста, как следует делать и какие способы быстрее работают.
Таблица примерная, по факту таблица содержит сотни строк.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: плывет потому что делаешь `rows[i].style.display = 'block';` у строк таблицы нужно устанавливать `display: table-row;`

Comment: а как задается класс `zero`?

Comment: Отправляю Json на страницу и при разборе json на странице, если все ячейки нули, то присваиваю класс zero.

Comment: Grundy, спасибо - работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

реализация в вопросе плывет, потому что делаешь

```
rows[i].style.display = 'block';
```

у строк таблицы нужно устанавливать `display: table-row;`

---

В качестве альтернативы пробеганию по нужным строкам в цикле и выставлении видимости вручную можно устанавливать класс контейнеру, например таблице, и в css указать, что находясь внутри этого класса элементы с классом zero будут иметь `display:none`.

В этом случае управление видимостью регулируется добавлением/удалением класса контейнеру

Пример:

```js
//js файл
function toggle() {
  document.querySelector('table').classList.toggle('hide-zero');
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```css
.hide-zero .zero {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
<label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

<table>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Ivanov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Petrov</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Sidorov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Morozov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tosterov</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Определённо лучше. Но насколько будет выигрыш?

Comment: @Other, в теории браузер может оптимизировать применение стиля и применять его быстрее чем ты пробежишь по элементам в яваскрипте. Но не думаю что различие будет заметно даже при тысяче строк

Comment: Да, скорости нынче не чета эры перфокарт. Но будет ли оптимизация в смысле отображения? Вроде новомодных штучек типа GPU для рендера.

Comment: @Other, Не понял на счет оптимизации в смысле отображения

Comment: В любом случае перерисовывать будет CSS, но будет ли заметно из-за постепенного изменения свойств или вид ждёт конца цикла? Т. е. может быть так, что браузер умён и не дёргает перерисовку до конца цикла (вроде с DOM есть подобные оптимизации).

Comment: Красивое решение, браво

Answer (score 3):

[`display`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display) - Янус в CSS.
Для `tr` он `table-row`, поэтому Ваш код работает, только нужно правильно установить `display` обратно:

```js
//js файл
function toggle() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.zero')).forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  });
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
    <label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

    <table>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Ivanov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Petrov</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Sidorov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="zero">
            <td>Morozov</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tosterov</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Всё равно есть смещение, если приглядеться

Comment: @Yuri, потому что ширина ячеек по содержимому растягивается, а в вопрос полностью вид изменялся

Comment: Где? И как? Chrome выдаёт `Perfect Pixel`.

Comment: Other, Grundy, спасибо, этот способ работает.А есть другие способы решить данную задачу ? P.S.Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.zero')).forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  }); очень похоже на лямбду в Java.

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, куча, но чем тебя не устраивает тот который уже работает?

Comment: @Grundy, для самообразования. Может опишите просто словами способы? я попробую их реализовать сам.

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, например, пробег в цикле, замена класса у контейнера, рендер _двух_ таблиц(с нулевыми строками и без) и подмена их по чекбоксу, перенос нулевых строк в невидимый контейнер, рендер таблицы по коллекции в яваскрипте.

Comment: @Grundy, а что работает быстрее , замена класса или смена стиля ?

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, _если хочешь узнать какая лошадь быстрее - устрой гонки_

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, нужно очень постараться, чтобы разница в скорости была ощутима. Но никто не будет одновременно отображать десятки тысяч строк, верно? А если будет, то оптимизировать нужно явно не способ сокрытия.

Comment: Ну я планирую многопользовательское приложение, поэтому кто сколько отображать будет пока не знаю :) Ну не десятки тысяч это точно.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы не плыло, можно вместо `display` изменять `visibility`:

```js
function toggle() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('zero');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked)
            rows[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        else
            rows[i].style.visibility = 'visible'
    }
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
<label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

<table>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Ivanov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrov</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Sidorov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Morozov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tosterov</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: слишком много пустых строк тогда

Comment: Странное решение. Правда.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#chkTest').on('change', function(){ //На событие изменения чекера вешаем функцию
  toggleZeroes();
})
function toggleZeroes(){
  var target = 'table'; //целевая таблица, в нашем случае, просто любая
  if(!$('#chkTest').prop('checked')){ //проверяем состояние чекера
    $(target).find('tr').show();//если он СТАЛ ВЫКЛЮЧЕН то показываем все строки
    return false; //выходим из ф-ции
  }
$(target).find('tr').each(function() {//Иначе - по каждой строке проходимся
  var total = 0;
  $(this).find('td').each(function() {// И считаем сумму всех ячеек этой строки
    var val = $(this).text()*1; //получаем значение ячейки, "*1" - необходимо, чтобы строго привести значение к числовому
    total += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0; //Если вдруг, ячейка содержит в себе значения, не переводящиеся в число, просто прибавляем к ней 0
  })
  if (total == 0) { //Если в строке сумма элементов - 0, прячем строку
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
<label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

<table>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Ivanov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Petrov</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Sidorov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="zero">
    <td>Morozov</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tosterov</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Немного костыльно, но рабоче.

Comment: JQuery мне еще рано, но спасибо :)

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, скорее уже поздно. `jQuery` морально своё изжил.

Comment: @Adrenal1ne, ну тут де-факто, только названия функций с JQuery - переменить на нативный JS, все тоже самое, ток выглядит несколько иначе, короче. Впрочем, я думаю, интуитивно понятно, что что делает.

Comment: @SLy_huh, у автора нулевые строки _уже_ отмечены классом

Comment: @Grundy ну вопрос был `Как можно по чекбоксу спрятать все строки таблицы, колонки которой содержат одни нули ?`. Решение с классами- авторское, и судя по всему, экспериментальное. Думаю, если предложить что-то более универсальное в использовании, хуже не будет.

Comment: @SLy_huh, совершенно верно. Если предлагают, что-то другое, то конечно же буду рассматривать данные варианты.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('zero');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked)
            rows[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        else
            rows[i].style.visibility = 'visible'
    }
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
<label for="chkTest">Hide all zero rows</label>

<table>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Ivanov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrov</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Sidorov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="zero">
        <td>Morozov</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tosterov</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]